# Apache virtual hosts without domain names, how to set a default site

Tags: apache, vhosts

I've set the following up to serve 2 development sites from the same box without using domain names:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /projecta /var/www/projecta
    Alias /projectb /var/www/projectb

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, but how do I direct requests for just the IP address, that is without a site name postfix, to a 'default' site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to redirect to defult site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /projecta  [R]
```